# How to know if any service (for example SQL Server service) is running or not from Microsoft OMS

Tags: sql-server, operation, suite

I am using Microsoft Operations Management Suite (OMS) to monitor my VMs. I want to know if my list of services (say SQL Server) is running on the VM or not?

How can I monitor this kind of information from OMS Workspace?

Thanks in Advance!

Regards
Sheetal.

Answer (score 0):

you create an alert to trigger whenever any sql server services stops by querying it. like below

```
Type=Event EventLog="System" Source="Service Control Manager" "The SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) service entered the stopped state."
```

Hope it helps